# Regular expression checking parameters

Tags: regex

I am a beginner with regexes, and I got this assignment to filter parameters with `-` and `--` joined with multiple alnums ending with `=` or without it. So positive catch would be `--input=` or `-help`

Here is my custom regex

```
^--((\w|-)*)(=([^\s]+))?$
```

the whole problem is that it does not catch `=` or `-`. For e.g. `-input` or `--input=` is not caught and I have no idea why.

Comment: Which regex dialect (i.e. programming language) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `?` for optional second hyphen. The pattern would become:

```
^--?([\w-]+)(?:=(\S*))?$
```

PS: `[^\s]` is same as `\S`.

Changing `+` to `*` allows for empty parameter values. When you use a `+`, the pattern expects `=` character to be followed by some value as well.